# Patterns of partially reused makefiles

Tags: git, go, makefile

I am at this time creating more and more of small one-off projects in golang but I see many makefile tasks are literally copy&paste from across projects. For example, in every project I have a:

```
${APP_NAME}: $(SOURCES)
    go get ./...
    goimports -w $(SOURCES)
    go build -o ${APP_NAME}
```

I would like to know if anyone has experience of fragment extraction into a separate project and importing it. If so, how do you do it?

- Just curl a file from `raw.githubusercontent.com`? Because that's what I'm about to do since I don't see any other easy way.
- I also thought about using git submodules but that seems also a bit over the top for a couple of files.

Comment: Many developers setup their editor to run goimports/gofmt.  There's no need to `go get ./...` unless you are pulling down something new.  If you name the directory containing the app "${APP_NAME}", then all you need to do is `go build`.  With this config, no makefile is needed.

Comment: I disagree. I have many many other tasks, the upper one is just one example. gometalinter, go-bindata, etc. Question remains although a particular example mentioned above can be avoided by some editor setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple workaround: I `include` Makefiles which I made from the starting monolithic Makefile.

I am putting split Makefiles in a separate git project, that contains only them.

I am referring to those Makefiles from root project and I have them locally via git submodule. A bit more work - yes, but it allows me to have trivial "root" Makefile and all hard (quite often - repeating) logic in the separate project.

Example of how I made this work:

- a split makefile project: https://github.com/milanaleksic/gomakefiles
- a root makefile that utilizes the upper project via submodule: https://github.com/milanaleksic/jenkins_ping